# get previous and next post titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, callback, blogger

im working to add next and previous navigation buttons to blogger starting from the default navigation and add titles of posts to it

i tried to get the titles of the posts using blogger feed but for some reason it says the callback functions are not defined

here is the code

```
 <a expr:href='data:olderPageUrl'>
                      <div class='older-post'>
                        <span class='pager_icon'><svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><polyline points='15 18 9 12 15 6'/></svg></span>
                        <span>prev</span>
                        <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><span class='older-text'><data:olderPageTitle/></span></a>
                      </div>
                    </a>
```

```
                    <a expr:href='data:newerPageUrl'>
                      <div class='newer-post'>
                        <span class='pager_icon'><svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><polyline points='9 18 15 12 9 6'/></svg></span>
                        <span>next</span>
                        <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'><span class='newer-text'><data:newerPageTitle/></span></a>
                      </div>
                    </a>
```

```
 /*********** Between Posts Navigation Starts ************/
  var olderLink = document.getElementById('Blog1_blog-pager-older-link');
  if (olderLink) {
    getPageTitle(olderLink, setOlderPageTitle);
    function setOlderPageTitle(data){
      setPageTitle(data, olderLink, '', '')
    };
  }
  var newerLink = document.getElementById('Blog1_blog-pager-newer-link');
  if (newerLink) {
    getPageTitle(newerLink, setNewerPageTitle);
    function setNewerPageTitle(data){
      setPageTitle(data, newerLink, '', '')
    };
  }
  // set the page title from feed data
  function setPageTitle(data, pageLink, prefix, suffix) {
    if (data.feed.entry) {
      if (data.feed.entry.length > 0) {
        var title = data.feed.entry[0].title.$t;
      }
    }
    if (title) {
      pageLink.innerHTML = prefix + title + suffix;
    }
  }
  // get entry data from the feed
  function getPageTitle(pageLink, callback) {
      var pathname = pageLink.getAttribute('href').replace(location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname, '');
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&max-results=1&redirect=false&path='+pathname+'&callback='+callback.name+'';
   var headTg =  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
 /*********** Between Posts Navigation End ************/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see where you define a number of functions yet there may be an issue of operational order since you define the functions after you may be calling the,

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  /*********** Between Posts Navigation Starts ************/
  var olderLink = $('#Blog1_blog-pager-older-link');
  var newerLink = $('#Blog1_blog-pager-newer-link');
  // set the page title from feed data
  function setPageTitle(data, pageLink, prefix, suffix) {
    if (data.feed.entry) {
      if (data.feed.entry.length > 0) {
        var title = data.feed.entry[0].title.$t;
      }
    }
    if (title) {
      pageLink.innerHTML = prefix + title + suffix;
    }
  }

  // get entry data from the feed
  function getPageTitle(pageLink, callback) {
    var pathname = pageLink.attr('href').replace(location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname, '');
    var script = $('<script>', {
      src: '/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&max-results=1&redirect=false&path=' + pathname + '&callback=' + callback.name
    }).appendTo("body");
  }

  function setOlderPageTitle(data) {
    setPageTitle(data, olderLink, '', '')
  };

  function setNewerPageTitle(data) {
    setPageTitle(data, newerLink, '', '')
  };

  if (olderLink) {
    getPageTitle(olderLink, setOlderPageTitle);
  }
  if (newerLink) {
    getPageTitle(newerLink, setNewerPageTitle);
  }
  /*********** Between Posts Navigation End ************/

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a expr:href='data:olderPageUrl'>
  <div class='older-post'>
    <span class='pager_icon'><svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><polyline points='15 18 9 12 15 6'/></svg></span>
    <span>prev</span>
    <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><span class='older-text'><data:olderPageTitle/></span></a>
  </div>
</a>

<a expr:href='data:newerPageUrl'>
  <div class='newer-post'>
    <span class='pager_icon'><svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><polyline points='9 18 15 12 9 6'/></svg></span>
    <span>next</span>
    <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'><span class='newer-text'><data:newerPageTitle/></span></a>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: i  manged to fix the problem which was simply excuting the function while loading dom and not after it other than that the function above worked just fine anyway thanks